# How do I make this query in django? (aggregation / annotation)

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Here is a part of my models.py:

```
class College(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class MyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    college = models.ForeignKey(College, blank=True,null=True,default=None)
```

As you can see, a user has some points, and many users will be part of a college. **Now, points of a college will be equal to sum of points of all the students in that college.** So, how do I send the list of colleges to my template, and obtain their respective points ?

(I want to create a ranking page of all colleges)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty standard aggregation query.

```
from django.db.models import Sum
colleges = College.objects.all().annotate(total_points=Sum('myuser__points'))
```